# Loading array of objects in Python from POST returns empty

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I am sending an array containing multiple object with POST Ajax like this:

```
var dateBooking = [];
    $(".dateBooking:enabled").each(function() {

        dateBooking.push({
            date: $(this).val(),
            hour: $(this).next('input').val()
        });
    });

    form_data.dateBooking = dateBooking;

$.ajax({
        url      :  "{% url "posts:book" %}",
        type  : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data     : form_data,
        success  : function(data, status){

        }
```

The data received in my Python View is like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'id': ['581'], 'dateBooking[0][hour]': [''], 'message': ['ttt'], 'dateBooking[0][date]': ['09/04/2018']}>
```

I can not access dateBooking. I tried:

```
dateBooking = request.POST.getlist('dateBooking[]')
```

which returns empty, and get gives an error.

Comment: You are posting JSON, not form data.

Comment: Where do you see this ?